# Vba Cell value as Expression

Tags: vba, expression

I have value in cell A1 ie. <10000 and i have value in VBA ie. 900 i want to compare VBA value with cell value expression.

example 1.

```
VBA Value is "900"
Excel expression (ie cell value) is "<10000"
result "TRUE"
```

example 2.

```
VBA Value is "20000"
Excel expression (ie cell value) is "<10000"
result "FALSE"
```

Comment: Look into `Evaluate`

Answer (score 0):

If you have `<1000` in `A1` something like this will return what you need

```
Sub TestMe
    Debug.Print CBool(Evaluate(900 & Cells(1,1)))
End Sub
```

Whole code, writing to `A1` and checking a `False` and `True` scenarios:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Cells(1, 1) = "<1000"
    Debug.Print Evaluate(900 & Cells(1, 1))
    Cells(1, 1) = ">1000"
    Debug.Print Evaluate(900 & Cells(1, 1))
End Sub
```

---

Concerning two condition, it depends how the condition is given. If the condition is given like this: `>5000000 and <10000000` then this code works:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Cells(1, 1) = ">5000000 and <10000000"
    Debug.Print Evaluate(900 & Trim(Split(Cells(1, 1), "and")(0))) And _
            Evaluate(900 & Trim(Split(Cells(1, 1), "and")(1)))
End Sub
```

Comment: what if cells value is is ">5000000 and <10000000" or ">5000000<10000000" than how we will evaluate?

Comment: @Mahesh - the same way. Change the place of `<1000` with `<5000000` and see the result.

Comment: there are two conditions in same cell ">5000000 and <10000000"... Greater than 500000 and less than 10000000